# Disable button click

Tags: android, button

I have a button with text apply.When user performs certain action the button text is changed to apply.Now when the text on the button is Applied , i wanna disable the button click.How can i achieve this.

Code

```
if (data.get (i).get ("status").equals ("null")) {
            holder.apply.setText ("Apply");
        } else {
            holder.apply.setText (data.get (i).get ("status"));
        }

        if (holder.apply.getText ().equals ("Applied")) {
            holder.apply.setFocusable (false);
            holder.apply.setClickable (false);
            holder.apply.setFocusableInTouchMode (false);
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to `Disabled` Button

```
 holder.apply.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (data.get (i).get ("status").equals ("null")) {
            holder.apply.setText ("Apply");
        } else {
            holder.apply.setText (data.get (i).get ("status"));
        }

        if (holder.apply.getText ().equals ("Applied")) {
            holder.apply.setEnabled(false);

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Write this line to disable your button:

```
holder.apply.setEnabled(false);
```